# How big is a Jhag horse

Tags: malazan

Through Karsa Orlong's storyline we see him riding his Jhag horse Havok (At first his fathers one and then later the one he gets on the Jhag Odhan). I estimate Karsa to be eight to nine feet tall and so I was wondering how big Havok, and Jhag horses in general, would be.

Comment: This seems such a simple question, and yet I can't find an answer in the books. In House of Chains Havok is described as: *another stallion, this one just entering adulthood*, so he is presumably slightly small than a fully adult stallion and bigger than the mares. And the books imply that Havok is about the same size relative to Karsa as normal horses are to normal humans.

Comment: The books do imply that about Havok's size. But at the same time there is a huge range in horse sizes that can be ridden. Mongolian horses are pretty tiny compared to European horses.

Comment: I would say Havoks about 1.5X bigger then your average horse given that Karsa is about 1.5X bigger then your average human. your average human being about 5'10-6' that puts karsa at around 9 feet. for average horse think european horses as they are the horses typically envisioned carried armored troops, for cavalry.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Malazan Wikia:

> Jhag horses were originally bred long ago by the Jaghut, they were
>   carnivorous. They were usually grey as iron with black manes and
>   tails. **Twice as large as a regular horse they were larger even than
>   the horses the Teblor had bred**. The mares were broad-backed. They were
>   drawn to the smell of bloodwood and blood oil.

So, basically twice the size of a normal horse, meaning *really big*.

Comment: The various Wikis are notoriously poor sources to quote from, though: they frequently contain information that is at best unsourced and therefore basically unverifiable, and at worst downright wrong and misleading as well. If you know of any canon source that corroborates the Wiki quote, please do add it in—that will greatly improve the answer.